# Calculate centroid of android.graphics.path values, and find the centroid's relative position w.r.t the path

Tags: android, centroid

If I have an `ArrayList` of `Path` values, how can I calculate the centroid for the figure generated by the created `Path` values? And then,how can I find the relative position of the centroid w.r.t the figure generated by the `Path`. Need guidance or help. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps you a little (from Android sources in 
`C:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\sources\android-17\android\gesture\GestureUtils.java` ):

```
/**
 * Calculates the centroid of a set of points.
 * 
 * @param points the points in the form of [x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn]
 * @return the centroid
 */
static float[] computeCentroid(float[] points) {
    float centerX = 0;
    float centerY = 0;
    int count = points.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        centerX += points[i];
        i++;
        centerY += points[i];
    }
    float[] center = new float[2];
    center[0] = 2 * centerX / count;
    center[1] = 2 * centerY / count;

    return center;
}
```